# What function does Wolfram Alpha plot instead of the factorial?

Tags: factorial, wolfram-alpha

Look to the second graph where  [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x!) gives a continuous factorial function:

What is the second graph?

It is not the gamma function, since that has $\Gamma(-1)=0!=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a plot of $\Gamma(x+1)$, known to equal $x!$ at integers.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you.